# How should I structure code when using form inheritance?

Tags: .net, winforms, oop

I am working on an application with 5 forms (1 form each for 5 different products). The products do share some common fields like for instance Name, Color, Weight etc, which make up about half of the fields on the form. The other half of the fields have no commonality at all.

To keep the application's look and feel consistent I put the common fields (controls) on a Base Form and then put the rest of the fields on the 5 Child Forms. Now obviously I would like to put the common code in the Base Form but I am not sure exactly the best way to do that.

For instance if I want to have a Sub to clear that textboxes at run time it would seem that I could put the code to clear the common controls in the base form and then do the fields that are different in the child forms but I am having trouble conceptualizing how that should be done.

Can someone provide some guidance for this relative OOP newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have a Clear function in your base form.  Your child form would inherit the Clear function and call mybase.clear(VB) to clear the common controls and then clear the unique controls.

Comment: For those of you following along be sure to change the Class Modifier in the parent form from Private (if it is) to something appropriate like Public, Protected or Friend or the child form won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to design the base Form.
After it's designed, all the design information will be passed by inheritance.

You should then expose just key members (that will be editable) via Properties.
These can be either protected or public (depending on what you're doing).

You could also add custom properties to the designer with [Design-Time Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx)